# Problems with IE6, SSL and Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, internet-explorer-6

We have a problem with a Zend framework-based PHP application. When accessed by IE6 over SSL, it occasionally fails silently, instantly producing "This page cannot be displayed" in IE and no log messages at all on the server - not even an Apache log reporting a bad request.

Here's what we've established so far:

1. Only IE6 produces this problem. Real browsers are fine, and even IE7.
2. Only using SSL produces this problem.
3. We're using a self-signed certificate.
4. A static HTML page does not produce the problem.
5. A simple "Hello world" PHP page does not produce the problem, but the full Zend application does.
6. Removing all external javascript and CSS from the delivered page has no effect
7. We've made sure the certificate is used by the `_default_:443` virtual host in Apache
8. The server is Ubuntu 3.0.0-12 running Apache 2.2.20, PHP 5.3.6
9. IE6 is running on Windows XP in a virtual machine
10. The virtual machine *does* have access to the internet
11. The virtual machine is not infested with malware

To us this suggests that the SSL handshake is failing, but we're confused by the fact that only a full Zend framework application triggers this - lesser PHP pages work fine.

Comment: This is why I just say "Screw IE" and don't care if it works in IE6 or not.

Comment: This is why http://www.trashinternetexplorer.com/ is one of my favorite sites.
I did not see you mention if this has actually worked in other browsers, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Please be careful with the word "Zend."  Zend is a company, not a product, not a service, not a library, not an IDE.  You'll need to specify which of Zend's *products* you're talking about here.  And now I get to watch the new tag page for the next few days to make sure people stop using the tag.  *Again*.

Comment: Does it function properly in Netscape Navigator?

Comment: Like I said in point 1, it works in every other browser we've tested. It didn't occur to me to try Netscape Navigator...

Answer (score 0):

This problem was related with a [Zend_Amf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.html) bug and fixed in ZF 1.11.11

Bug details: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11776